# rails get json from url and md5 hash it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, md5, json

Why do i get every 4th or 5th request a different MD5 hash returned?

```
url = "http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien:BEZIRKSGRENZEOGD&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json"
        response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
        data = response.body
        result = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(data)

        jsonHash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(data)
        puts jsonHash
```

jsonHash is sometimes a843a3e2dcffb9b1940ea4a48bf260f0
and sometimes 9b0d15b9f97c542b07bde361be64edcd

The Data from the url never changes.. this is some static JSON.. Why does this not work!?

Comment: Apparently, some of the data you hash changes. Look closer. Maybe fields in the json get reordered or something like that.

Comment: Maybe a timestamp in the response?

Comment: no.. because it is just those to checksums that i get returned...

Comment: ok i did the download with wget a few times and dumped it in a text file... often its the same.. but sometimes its different.. and then i did a diff on these 2 files.. and it seems that all data is different.. but if i open it by hand and have a look they seem completly the same :/